# How can i fix the Oracle Enerprise Manager error - Agent is blocked?

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have installed `OEM 12c` and after restarting my oms the agents got the following error:

```
Heartbeat Status : Agent is blocked
Blocked Reason : Plugin mismatch found between agent and repository. 
I have restarted the agent but sill no success.
```

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you re-sync your agent using the EM GUI ! 
[Here is a article showing how this is done !](http://www.aodba.com/en/blog/2014/12/09/fix-oracle-em-error-agent-blocked/)

**In short :**

Check your agent status :

```
./emctl status agent

Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c Release 3
Copyright (c) 1996, 2013 Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.
---------------------------------------------------------------
Agent Version : 12.1.0.3.0
OMS Version : (unknown)
Protocol Version : 12.1.0.1.0
Agent Home : /em_agent12.3/agent_inst
Agent Binaries : /em_agent12.3/core/12.1.0.3.0
Agent Process ID : 64164
Parent Process ID : 64110
Agent URL : https://bih002:3872/emd/main/
Repository URL : https://dcg023:4900/empbs/upload
Started at : 2013-11-13 15:26:08
Started by user : em_user
Last Reload : (none)
Last successful upload : (none)
Last attempted upload : 2013-11-13 15:26:14
Total Megabytes of XML files uploaded so far : 0
Number of XML files pending upload : 72
Size of XML files pending upload(MB) : 0.11
Available disk space on upload filesystem : 91.16%
Collection Status : Collections enabled
Heartbeat Status : **Agent is blocked**
```

Next re-sync your agent using the GUI:
[image]

Now check you agent status again!